# How to make my own private blockchain?

Tags: polygon, explorers, blockchain-fork

I would like to launch my own private blockchain based on polygon.
I googled for it, but I think my googling skill is not good because I can not get any useful URL for it.
Can someone please help me on this?

- I would like to make my own private blockchain and running it on my own VPS.(no need to modify anything on blockchain, just need to confirm txs, make smart contract, and get mother wallet)
- I would like to make a scan like https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/ for my own private blockchain. I think I can do this by forking one of the blockchain explorer sample.

It will be very thankful if someone give useful links for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So for running you own private chain you basically need to create and configure your genesis.json file and define a networkId when running your blockchain client.

For tweaking deeper configs you should provide your-custom-config.toml file when starting up your node:
`geth --datadir ./your-persistence-folder --networkid 1234 --config ./my-custom-cfg.toml`
This file has a lot of configuration options, so is easier to let the node generate one for you, and use it as a template. For generating a config file as a scaffold you just need to call the "dumpconfig" command: `geth --gorli dumpconfig > my-cfg-template.toml` then you change the values in this file as you need.

For running your own scan, as you sad, you can fork any available scan out there, if you don't have any specific blockchain client and blockscan in mind, I would recommend you to see the [Otterscan](https://github.com/wmitsuda/otterscan), that is a really fast block explorer and have a pretty rich API.

I would recommend you the following references:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#operating-a-private-network
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/command-line-options
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/config-files

Furthermore, running your private polygon node is pretty similar of running an ethereum one, the key difference is that you will be running a polygon client binary, the same commands that I described applies for Polygon too, you're gonna need to provide networkid and genesis.json file. Here `https://github.com/maticnetwork/erigon` you can find more info about running an Erigon client for Polygon. And [here](https://github.com/maticnetwork/blockscout) you can find more info for running you blockscan. I think it's better to figure it out how to run you private node looking to Ethereum first, because there are more resources out there, and then you can just apply the same concepts using a Polygon node. I hope this help you @DreamPerson.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Daniel.
But friend, I need to fork polygon not ethereum.

And also what I need is not a fast explorer. I would like to get a explorer repo which will work with only set .env a little. I hope to set only databaes and provider URL.